# "weird" Google Chrome feature, huge address bar pops up

Tags: google-chrome

I am quite puzzled by this feature since it just seems off.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>* and I'm not in a text box.

*(basically the key below the <kbd>+</kbd>, left of <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

I get this:

[image]

A huge address bar where I can type (in this case I had typed google.com - it's not by default). The with <kbd>Enter</kbd> it goes to that address.

I does not have all the extra omnibar functionalities.

I am very intrigued as to why this feature is there, it seems useless (specially having <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>), it doesn't "fit" the design either.

So if anyone has any ideas as to why that is there, I would like to hear it.

Thank in advance!

Comment: If anyone would like to create the tag address-bar, you are welcome to re-tag my question, Thanks!!

Comment: lol , report it as a bug, i can't make the adress bar look like that, funny though

Comment: It might have something to do with accessibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a feature of some extension you have installed.

Comment: Agreed. This is not standard Chrome behaviour and the OP already seem to have extensions installed.

Comment: Ok that was silly of me, but I actually had discarded that because it was working on  incognito mode. It turns out I had The [goo.gl extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iblijlcdoidgdpfknkckljiocdbnlagk) enabled there too, this is BTW what is causing it. (Still puzzled for it's use though :) ) Thank you!